# Build Svelte component for NPM using vite

Tags: svelte, vite

I currently have the following files. But I am unsure how to edit my `vite.config.ts` file so that I can push it to NPM. Ideally, I want it to export out a file so I can do the following in other projects:

```
import MyComponent from "mycomponent"
```

I can't find any documentation anywhere on how to do this.

**/src/MyComponent.svelte**

```
<button>My component</button>
```

**/src/main.ts**

```
export { default as MyComponent } from './MyComponent.svelte';
```

**/vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()]
})
```

Comment: You should read up on [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) first...

Comment: @H.B. I've read this entire page. And not a single svelte example. I still want it to be a "svelte" specific component. Not a browser first one.

Comment: It's not specific to Svelte, it is completely irrelevant what type of component you build or framework you use.